# Check multiple checkboxes and apply styles

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have multiple checkboxes and I want to apply styles only to the checkbox selected by the user.

I have in all the inputs a class called form-check-input which I call from js with a queryselectorall.

The problem is that I can't detect the change of checkbox selection so that the styles are applied only to the one that the user selected.

The code:

```
<label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault3">
<input class="form-check-input" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" type="radio" 
name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault3"></label>
```

(I have 3 of these)

JS Code:

```
let checkGral = document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-input');
let selected = document.querySelector('.planes')

function toggleCheckbox() {
if (selected.checked) {
selected.style.border = '1px solid #0000FF';
} 
}
```

Image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: You can also use the `:checked` pseudo-class in CSS directly. `input[type="radio"]:checked`

Comment: In the onChange event handler, I suggest removing the border setting for all "form-check-label" labels first and then setting the border setting for the select "form-check-label" label.

Comment: Try putting the `let selected = document.querySelector('.planes')` inside the function

Answer (score 0):

You can manage border style by class.

- try using `addEventListener` instead of inline html event handler
- set `addEventListener` to upper container for event delegation 
  ex)"form-container"

### example solution

```js
const checkGral = document.querySelector(".form-container");
checkGral.addEventListener("click", toggleCheckbox);

function toggleCheckbox(e) {
  if(!e.target.classList.contains('form-check-input')) return;

  const box = e.target.closest(".planes");
  const planes = document
    .querySelectorAll("div.planes")
    .forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("selected"));
  box.classList.add("selected");
}
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="planes">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
       checkbox1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="planes">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2">
       checkbox2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="planes">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault3">
       checkbox3
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```